# Using git push heroku --all get a problem

Tags: git, heroku

I have type

`git add .`

`git commit -m "test"`

But when I type this:

`git push heroku --all`

It just stop showing text except following text:

`Username for 'https://git.heroku.com':`

Unlike another question that get

```
Username for 'https://git.heroku.com': <email>
Password for 'https://<email>@git.heroku.com':
```

I just get `Username for 'https://git.heroku.com':`

And I need to close cmd.exe to stop it.

Comment: So did you try providing your username?

Comment: I have use ```Heroku login```.

It open a web and I login heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$ heroku auth:login` and log in using your credentials, this should work.

If you have already tried that try:

`$ heroku auth:token`

Username = ...

Password = `$ heroku auth:token`

Comment: heroku auth:token
 »   Warning: token will expire 10/17/2020
 »   Use heroku authorizations:create to generate a long-term token
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

D:\test>git push heroku --all
Username for 'https://git.heroku.com': 

Still shutdown at this text.

Comment: Generate an auth token and put it in as the password.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where to put in.
`.git/config` or `heroku config:set` or .....?